# Django. Create object ManyToManyField error

Tags: python, django, testing

I am trying to write tests for my models.

I try to create object like this:

```
    GiftEn.objects.create(gift_id=1,
    name="GiftEn",
    description="GiftEn description",
    short_description="GiftEn short description",
    categories='1',
    partner='1',
    addresses=2)
```

But i get this error:

```
File "/home/stasman/giver/giver/giver/gift/test_gift.py", line 29, in setUp
    addresses=2)

ValueError: "<GiftEn: GiftEn, GiftEn description, GiftEn short description>" needs to have a value for field "giften" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Here is my model:

```
class GiftEn(models.Model):
    gift = models.ForeignKey(Private, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryEn,)
    partner= models.ManyToManyField(Partner,)
    addresses= models.ManyToManyField(AddressWhereTakeGift,)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s' % (self.name, self.description, self.short_description)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-gift__id',)
```

How to create object for this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By error description you need create (save) `GiftEn` object before add many2many:

```
giften = GiftEn.objects.create(
    gift_id=1,
    name="GiftEn",
    description="GiftEn description",
    short_description="GiftEn short description")

giften.categories.add('1')
giften.partner.add('1')
giften.addresses.add(2)
```

Comment: Its `'1'` not `1`